# SELECT with INNER JOIN doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get rows from my table which:
-has the same id like parameter
-has date lower than today

This is my tasks table structure:

```
id | title | project_id | date
```

And projects table:

```
id | name
```

So, my query should give me name of project too.

I wrote something like this:

```
$query= 'SELECT *
        FROM tasks WHERE (user_id = :id AND date < CURDATE())
        INNER JOIN projects
        WHERE project_id = projects.id';
```

What is incorrect here?

Without combining INNER JOIN and WHERE, queries works fine:

```
'SELECT * FROM tasks INNER JOIN projects WHERE project_id = projects.id';

'SELECT * FROM tasks FROM tasks WHERE (user_id = :id AND date < CURDATE())'
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

---

*:id parameter is binding with PDO (correctly for sure)*

Answer (score 3):

The `where` clause comes after the `group by`. Also, use proper `ON` clause to do the joining.

```
select *
from tasks
join projects on tasks.project_id = projects.id
where user_id = :id
    and date < CURDATE()
```